# How do I return a List from Tornado?

Tags: json, list, tornado

I'm trying to to get tornado to return a list.

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self, param):

    ...
    someList = [bla,bla,bla]

    self.finish(someList)
```

but whenever I do I get

```
HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='tornado', method='GET', uri='/orders/submitted', version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Host': 'tornado', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'close', 'Referer': 'admin/', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Cookie': 'login="dHJ1ZQ==|1392074972|f4942e30293413717b380d1f362dd549548c404d"'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1221, in _when_complete
    if result.result() is not None:
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 129, in result
    raise_exc_info(self.__exc_info)
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 574, in inner
    self.set_result(key, result)
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 500, in set_result
    self.run()
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 531, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(next)
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/fabfile/server/request_handlers/orders.py", line 26, in get
    self.finish((u"hi",))
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 810, in finish
    self.write(chunk)
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 610, in write
    chunk = utf8(chunk)
  File "/Users/ruahman/swipe-tech-apps/rpm-tornado/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 203, in utf8
    "Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got %r" % type(value)
TypeError: Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got <type 'tuple'>
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /orders/submitted (127.0.0.1) 8424.93ms
```

I don't have this problem when I return a dictionary.  it only happens when I return array.
yes I could embed the list in a object but I prefer the result to be an array.

Answer (score 19):

For complicated reasons, it is a security risk to use an array as the top-level structure of a JSON object on the Web. Thus, Tornado doesn't automatically convert lists to JSON, only dicts. I suggest you embed the list in a dict:

```
self.finish({'someList': someList})
```

If you insist on returning the list directly, you can JSON-encode it yourself:

```
self.finish(json.dumps(someList))
```

Here is an explanation of the security vulnerability related to using top-level JSON arrays in a web API:

- [Anatomy of a Subtle JSON Vulnerability](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/)
- [JSON Hijacking](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/)

Comment: Is there anything else I can answer for you, or will you accept this as the answer?

Comment: @a-jesse-jiryu-davis  you mentioned returning arrays as a security risk, I tried to read about it but cant find anything credible. would it be possible to share some good reference i can read up.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to one of the popular explanations of the vulnerability.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis, a quick question: when you JSON-encode the data yourself before returning it by calling `self.finish(json_encoded_data)`, do you need to set the appropriate response header, or this is handled automatically by Tornado (as is the case for `self.finish(some_dict)`)?

Comment: Good point, you need to set Content-Type header. Of course you can easily answer the question for yourself with "curl -I" and the URL of your handler.